# Sublime 3, regex, find in one place, change somewhere else in the same file

Tags: regex, search, replace, sublimetext

I have several xml files that I'm trying to update "automatically".

It looks like this:

```
<root>
    <lang_ref>en</lang_ref>
    <other_stuff>blablab</other_stuff>
    ...
    ...
    <markup>
        <p>
            <a href="http://my.domain.com/lang/en/">Text link</a>
        </p>
    </markup>
</root>
```

I need to update the xml to change the links in the href (for instance http://my.newdomain.com/lang/en/). The xml files all have different languages, defined in the `<lang_ref>` tag and the link needs to be "translated" for each language

So basically I would need a regex (or any other method) that takes the language in the lang_ref tag to replace the link to http://my.newdomain.com/lang/[lang_ref]/

Note : I already have RegReplace installed

Comment: In general, a regex is not a good approach with XML (or HTML). XSLT would be my preference: a transform that largely copies the XML, except for using the value from `lang_ref` to modify the URL.

Comment: Mh, sorry, I'll update my question, maybe it was unclear. It's the source XML that I need to change. (so that it can be processed by the xslt engine afterwards)

Comment: In that case I would definitely go with XSLT: already have the infrastructure (and if an XSLT engine won't update inplace then write to temporary file and replace original).

Comment: We have an XSLT engine that is already processing the XMLs, I need  to change the source XML, not the other way around. The XSL is used accross a lot of different pages and there's no reason to tell the XSL to change this link, since the link might be correct for other pages.

Comment: So why can't you use one transform before passing onwards to the main XSLT? (Regex is the wrong solution here, matching a substantial part of the document, to include both the replacement value and where you're replacing, only to largely re-create it in the replacement will be hard to get right and, at best, fragile.)

Comment: Because, unfortunately, the platform we're using doesn't allow multiple XSL transformation. Only one. Also, the regex in sublime would be perfect for me since the structure of the XMLs also change from one to another (but the lang_ref stays and the link too)